# Entity Framework 7 run sql scripts before and after table(s) creation

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-core

I want to run some custom sql scripts before and after EF7 decides to go off and create all the tables.

What level of control can I have??

For example, I want to create a table with a computed, persisted column. This column requires a function to exist (will be a sql-clr function in this case). Hence the function needs to exists before the tables are created. E.g. can I do something like

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Person>()
            .Property(p => p.DisplayValue)
            .HasComputedColumnSql("[dbo].[GetDisplayValue]([Value]) PERSISTED");
```

Is this even possible?

Furthermore I need to also run scripts after the tables have been created, e.g.
Adding fulltext catalogs, fulltext indexes and stored procs.

Am I just going about this incorrectly? Is it better for me to setup my database by, for example, the visual studio sql project (or whatever means), and disable migrations in EF7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can modify the migrations code, and add your own SQL commands using the Sql method